# Why is the effect of newlines in F# different for certain expressions, and (arguably) counter-intuitive in some of them?

Tags: f#, boolean, operator-precedence

*Disclaimer/edit: this is a fairly simple question, but I'm asking it since I'm (still) often confused by evaluation order in F#, esp. with respect to newlines vs. spaces. Trial and error always gets me where I want to, but I don't think you can really understand a language if you have to resort to trial and error.*

If I write:

```
let res x =
    x * 1 = x
    |> ignore
```

all's fine, but if I write:

```
let res x =
    x * 1 = x && x * -1 = -x
    |> ignore
```

then the compiler complains (it says it expects `bool -> bool`, not `bool -> unit`). I would have expected the newline to act as a separator here.

Adding parentheses helps, and putting it on one line shows that it is evaluated as `(X && (Y |> Z))`, where `X` and `Y` are boolean expressions and `Z` is any function.

Is this true? And is there a simpler way to find this out? Or better, when is whitespace a significant operator and when not?

---

To give another example:

```
let v = x |> fun x -> float x |> fun y -> true
```

Why is `y` here of type float and not of type `int -> float`? This may be obvious, and I sure have programmed thousands of lines that way, it even feels *natural*, but why?

If the only answer to give is "operator precedence and `->` comes before `|>`", so be it. But I guess/hope there's some more academical or otherwise formal though behind all this (and I still find it odd that `&&` has lower prio than `|>`, again, I don't understand why and in that case it feels counter-intuitive).

Comment: Looks like you need to add parenthesis in this expression: ``(x * 1 = x && x * -1 = -x)``

Comment: @gustavo, I know, that's what I wrote. But that's not the question here... :)

Comment: Then what is your question? From what I read your guess is correct.

Comment: @gustavo I always thought that newlines are just another operator, similar to `;`. It's often not ignorable as just whitespace. So what's the rule here?

Comment: @gustavo, I edited my question. Perhaps this helps. I don't get the downvote either. I always appreciate it if downvoters at least give you a chance to improve your question by giving a comment.

Comment: I think that newlines would act as separator when using let bindings, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsyme/2006/08/23/lightweight-syntax-option-in-f-1-1-12-3/  but if it doesn't fall in those cases (as in the forward pipe) it's not affected by the light syntax.

Comment: FWIW, I still often resort to trial and error, and I've been writing F# on/off for six years...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/#operator-precedence it seems that `&&` has higher precedence than `|>` so your guess is correct and you need to add parenthesis:

```
let res x =
  (x * 1 = x && x * -1 = -x)
  |> ignore
```

It looks like a new line doesn't act as a separator unless it has a let binding or fall in one of the rules listed [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsyme/2006/08/23/lightweight-syntax-option-in-f-1-1-12-3/)

For example if you take this expression:

```
let res = 
  5 + 1
    .GetType()
```

You also get an error, because it applies the `.` operator to `1` not to the whole expression, so the precedence rules still holds, regardless of the newline.

Comment: This is definitely _one_ valid answer to the question, thanks. I edited my question to hopefully give a better grasp of what I am after. It is very well possible that the answer is along the line "it is what it is, since it is defined that way", than so be it ;).